# Bash script to verify validity of SVN projects

Tags: linux, bash, shell, svn

I'd like to write a bash script that runs every week and essentially executes the svnadmin verify script on all the projects stored on the server. This should be easy enough to do but I don't have enough knowledge of bash to write this script, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The projects are stored in one directory on the server so I'd like to output the standard ls -la command and at the end of each directory name (the projects) and state whether the project is OK or not (whether the verify command has completed running on said project).

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Is your problem in writing this verification script or making it run once a week?

Comment: It's in writing the script, making it run once a week won't be an issue as I've scheduled tasks in Linux before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test the exit status of `svnadmin verify` in a loop iterating over all directories (using the directory glob operator `*/`) of a given parent, e.g. `svndir`:

```
#!/bin/bash

svndir=/home/subversion/repositories

for dir in "$svndir"/*/
do
    if svnadmin verify "$dir" &>/dev/null
    then
        echo -n "OK  "
    else
        echo -n "NOK "
    fi
    ls -lad "$dir"
done
```

This example will discard the progress output of `svnadmin verify`. Note that it may also print `OK` if `svnadmin verify` is interrupted (e.g. with `^C`) and it will print `NOK` on subdirectories that are not a repository.